# Why is my DropDownList outputting the wrong value for the first list item only?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, webforms, drop-down-menu

I load cities from the data context into two different lists and bind them to their respective DropDownList controls.

Although the code is the same for both, and only the data and obviously the name of the controls are different, the data binding seems to not work properly for only one of them. Instead of displaying the city name, it displays its Id, that is, for the first option only!

We have two DropDownList controls:

1. `DestinationDropDownList`;
2. `OriginDropDownList`.

Then, I populate them.

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!IsPostBack) {
            var instruction = new City() {
                CityId = Guid.Empty,
                CityName = "- Select a city -"
            };

            var destinations = context.Cities.ToList();
            destinations = destinations.OrderBy(c => c.CityName).ToList();
            destinations.Insert(0, instruction);
            DestinationDropDownList.DataSource = destinations;
            DestinationDropDownList.DataTextField = "CityName";
            DestinationDropDownList.DataValueField = "CityId";
            DestinationDropDownList.DataBind();

            var origins = context.Cities.ToList();
            origins = origins.OrderBy(c => c.CityName).ToList();
            origins.Insert(0, instruction);
            OriginDropDownList.DataSource = origins;
            OriginDropDownList.DataTextField = "CityName";
            OriginDropDownList.DataValueField = "CityId";
            OriginDropDownList.DataBind();
        }
    }
    private static readonly MyDataContext context = new MyDataContext();
}
```

HTML:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DestinationDropDownList" runat="server" />
<asp:DropDownList ID="OriginDropDownList" runat="server" />
```

Data displayed:

```
*DestinationDropwDownList*
    - 0000-0000-0000-0000-0000 (empty Guid)
    - CityName 01
    - CityName 02
    - ...

*OriginDropDownList*
    - - Select a city -
    - CityName 01
    - CityName 02
    - ...
```

The correct display is the one rendered by `OriginDropDownList` control. Why is `DestinationDropDownList` not displaying the data correctly, that is, for the first and only the first item in its list?

1. I tried removing the first item before inserting the instruction;
2. I tried to insert the instruction twice, then remove the first one;
3. I tried to go along with the `DropDownList.Items.Add(string)` method, and this was displaying nothing as for the first row, instead the the empty Guid.

How can I correct this behaviour!?

Comment: Im not able to reproduce this issue...

Comment: JonH: I'm somewhat glad you can't, because it is such a pain when it happens! ;) Thanks for your grain of salt! =)

Comment: I just cant understand why this is happening to you...

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `DestinationDropDownList.DataBind()` and debug your app. After executing that line, what is the value of `DestinationDropDownList.Items[0].Text`?

Comment: Micheal: `DestinationDropDownList.Items[0].Text == "- Choisir -"`, so the display should be okay. Aside, when I do a QuickWatch over it, the `DestinationDropDownList.Text == Guid.Empty`, and that is what gets displayed instead of the actual selected item. Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't encountered this issue before, but I will try to answer your second question. I see little value in adding the first 'instructional' item through code (correct me if I'm wrong). I'd rather add it directly to the mark-up:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DestinationDropDownList" runat="server"
  AppendDataBoundItems="true"
  DataTextField="CityName"
  DataTextField="CityId">
  <asp:ListItem Text="- Select a city -" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

The first item will survive the data binding due to the use of the [`AppendDataBoundItems`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.appenddatabounditems.aspx) attribute. I also added the `DataTextField` and `DataValueField` attributes, you can remove those from the code as well.

Another thing you can do before data binding, is projecting the entities to `ListItem` instances:

```
DestinationDropDownList.DataSource = 
  from d in destinations
  select new ListItem() {
    Text = d.CityName,
    Value = d.CityId.ToString()
  };
DestinationDropDownList.DataBind();
```

This way, you don't have to set the `DataTextField` or `DataValueField` properties on the control as you are already creating the list's items yourself.

Comment: I didn't know about that one! Let me try it out and see what happens. =) Thanks!

Comment: +1 for teaching me a way I didn't know about. - Adding the first `ListItem` as you do works good, as I can see the item even after the data binding occurs. However, only for first item, it is its value that is displayed, so I will keep seeing the `Guid.Empty` value. It looks like it does this only with the first item in the list, as I can see my instruction from the one I inserted in the code.

Comment: As for my point to make it through code, it's just because this was the way to do it in Windows Forms. I'm quite a beginner in Web development, so I'm not yet really acquainted with these HTML and ASP.NET tags and attributes. I rather see C# code, I'm under the impression that it lets me a better control over the controls and what happens in the page in the overall. =)

Comment: @WillMarcouiller Are you saying that even with the `Text` attribute set in mark-up for the first item it's still displaying 0000-0000...? I have tweaked the code a bit more, see if that helps.

Comment: I actually used your way of data binding for the first item, setting the `ListItem.Value` property to `"- Select a city -"`. I removed the instruction insert from the code, and the results is exactly what I wanted it to do. I just don't yet get how this can happen, unfortunately. We found a way to workaround, but this is not the real solution, as your exact code should do the trick. Anyway! Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: No problem. I added another edit, wich may prevent the issue altogether (using projection which will prevent reflection during data binding). See if you can combine it with what you already have. I concur with some of the commenters, it's a strange issue and you may consider contacting Microsoft support if you want to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Yes, it does. Setting the `Text` attribute in the HTML or in the code through data binding results with the exact same behaviour. At least, I feel less dirty if I trick it through HTML markup than in the code directly.

Comment: In your latest edit, please add a `ToString()` following `d.CityId` as the `Value` property has to be a string. =)

Comment: It works flawlessly with your latest edit! The `Text` property is displayed correctly with no tricks at all! Cool! Thanks for your help! I cannot upvote again, but I'd do if I could as happy as I am now! =)